# Should I use a package manager?

Tags: macos, install, package-management

**I want to keep keep track of which files belong to which application**, so that when I uninstall an application, I can be sure all of its files are gone, *including configuration files, dependencies it might have installed, etc.*

1. There are GUI applications that can be downloaded and just **dragged and dropped** into the Applications folder, like *GIMP* or *TextMate*. Is this the best way to install those apps, or should I use a package manager for them? Can I be sure that these applications do not install anything outside of their Application folder? Is deleting an app from the Application folder a "clean" uninstall?
2. There are applications such as *Python* which come with an **installer** (*.mpkg*). Is using that installer the best way to install these apps, or should I use a package manager for them? How do I find out which files these installers touched, and how would I undo everything that installer does in a clean way?

I'm interested in some kind of **best practices**, for which using a package manager is recommended, and when just installing it like said above is "clean" enough.

Comment: If you do not mind having a additional burden to your CPU/kernel in keeping track of those then yes. there are simple programs (that I use) to do the same and they only look for the family when you want to uninstall

Comment: Can you name one of these "simple programs"? And what would be the advantage of using that instead of a full fledged package manager?

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not install and uninstall multitude of apps daily, I prefer to use something that will not constantly burden my system like a package manager may do.

I use a very simple but very effective app called [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (what a name), that is only running when I ask for it.

[image: AppCleaner]

It will find all the related files to a given app and show them to me before I hit delete.

It allows the deselection of drivers ect. if you want to keep them for some reason.